# Erro Login Facebook React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Estou tendo problemas ao fazer o `login` no `react-native`, segui todos os passos correspondentes, e na hora de `logar` apresenta o seguinte erro

> `cannot read property 'logInWithReadPermissions' of undefined`

```
import FBDSK, { LoginManager } from 'react-native-fbsdk'

_fbAuth() {

        LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then(
            function(result) {
                if (result.isCancelled) {
                    alert('Login cancelled');
                } else {
                    alert('Login success with permissions: ' +
                        result.grantedPermissions.toString());
                }
            },
            function(error) {
                alert('Login fail with error: ' + error);
            }
        );

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tentou setar o ambiente de Login?

Exemplo:

`LoginManager.setLoginBehavior(LoginManager.LoginBehaviors.Native);
 LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then(
            function(result) {
                if (result.isCancelled) {
                    alert('Login cancelled');
                } else {
                    alert('Login success with permissions: ' +
                        result.grantedPermissions.toString());
                }
            },
            function(error) {
                alert('Login fail with error: ' + error);
            }
        );`

Acho que isso deve solucionar seu problema